# ConnectionRefusedError: Unable to connect MySQL container while building docker image for a flask app

Tags: mysql, docker, flask, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to build docker image for a flask app.The app uses another MySQL docker image as a dependency and I get the following error log

```
Generating a RSA private key
db_1   | ..+++++
db_1   | ..........................................................................+++++
db_1   | unable to write 'random state'
db_1   | writing new private key to 'client-key.pem'
db_1   | -----
db_1   | Certificates initialized
db_1   | MySQL init process in progress...
web_1  | Connecting root@127.0.0.1:3306
web_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 583, in connect
web_1  |     **kwargs)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 724, in create_connection
web_1  |     raise err
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 713, in create_connection
web_1  |     sock.connect(sa)
web_1  | ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refusedweb_1  | Connecting root@127.0.0.1:3306
web_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 583, in connect
```

Below is my Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml

Dockerfile

```
# this is an official Python runtime, used as the parent image
FROM python:3.6.5-slim

# set the working directory in the container to /app



ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
# unblock port 80 for the Flask app to run on
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app/datajoint-python
RUN pip install -e datajoint-python
EXPOSE 1234
CMD ["python", "run.py"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "1234:1234"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - "db"
    restart: always
  db:
    image: datajoint/mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=simple
      - MYSQL_USER=root
    restart: always
```

I have tried alot of things like copying the id_rsa file in my app directory. But, I am unable to figure out why the error is coming up .
I build and try to run everything by executing

```
sudo docker-compose up
```

I am running all of this on MacOS. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your web container is trying to connect to the MySQL instance before it is up and ready for serving requests. The `depends_on:` is not enough to fix the dependency.

```
db_1   | MySQL init process in progress...
web_1  | Connecting root@127.0.0.1:3306
web_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
```

You can fix this issue, by introducing a wait for functionality for your web applications, to do so change your docker file to

```
# this is an official Python runtime, used as the parent image
FROM python:3.6.5-slim

ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install netcat -y
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
# unblock port 80 for the Flask app to run on
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app/datajoint-python
RUN pip install -e datajoint-python
EXPOSE 1234
COPY ./docker-entrypoint.sh /
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

add a docker-entrypoint.sh (chmod a+x)

```
#!/bin/sh -e

until nc -vz db:3306 > /dev/null; do
    >&2 echo "db:3306 is unavailable - sleeping"
    sleep 2
  done
  >&2 echo "db:3306 is up"

python run.py

exit 0
```

Comment: If the entrypoint file ends with `exec "$@"`, it can reuse the `CMD` from the original Dockerfile.  That's a useful pattern in case you want to run something else (say, a debugging shell) with the same initial setup.

Comment: @wshihadeh it keeps on printing logs like the following. Maybe it is unable to connect to db, do you have any idea ?         web_1 | db:3306 is unavailable - sleeping web_1 | db:3306: forward host lookup failed: Unknown host

Comment: it seems that the web container cant resolves the database container name.  `db:3306` is the database service name and port . can you verify that these are the correct ones from your docker-compose?

Comment: Going by the shell script you added in your response, I tested with the folllowing command on MAC terminal nc -v localhost 3306 and it says Connection to localhost port 3306 [tcp/mysql] succeeded! do you think i can replace this command in the script to get it working ?

Comment: On making the above change, i get the following log localhost [127.0.0.1] 3306 (mysql) : Connection refused
web_1  | db:3306 is unavailable - sleeping ,                                                     name of container is datajoint/mysql

Comment: you cant use the localhost inside the container . can you check if the db and web. belong to the same network or not ? `docker inspect db| grep NetworkID` and docker inspect db | grep IPAddress

Comment: @wshihadeh Network Id is same for both but Ip address is different. Ip address for db ( loris_db_1) is 172.18.0.2 and web (loris_web_1) is 172.18.0.3.

Comment: That is weird , they are in the same network they should able to talk to each other. can you try to rename the `db` service to something like `mysql` in the docker compose and entry file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209898/discussion-between-ishaan-arora-and-al-waleed-shihadeh).